# Unity3D - Don't compile if package name doesn't exist

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Is it possible to "gray out" the code if it doesn't exist like we do in Platform Dependent compilation (ex: #If UNITY_EDITOR)?

For example I don't want the compiler to complain if the code doesn't exist in the project. Specifically, I want to "hide"  "GoogleMobileAds.Api;" package, which I don't have in the project, but it may be in the future.

Comment: What code are you trying to hide? `using` directives, or something else? It's not clear to me why hiding and ignoring basically-invalid code is better than deleting it. You could always put it within a `#if GOOGLE_MOBILE_ADS` directive, of course...

Comment: I'm writing my own codebase and I want to have two different projects. One with my code and another one with code that uses third party SDK (Ads, IAP, various analytics etc). Don't ask me, why but this is the most efficient approach I've come across since I have multiple platforms to publish and different SDKs don't support multiple platforms. Anyway, since I already have the code that I coded for Admob, it would be better if I could just "hide" that script so the compiler won't complain until that SDK is actually imported in another project....

Comment: Wait.. GOOGLE_MOBILE_ADS directive actually works! This is what I need. How did you know this exact directive exist? IDE doesn't give the the suggestion about that directive.

Comment: I want to find other directives for other packages too like firebase.

Comment: hm. it actually doesn't work. In the project where admob package exists, the code with this directive is still greyed out.

Comment: That wasn't any kind of "predetermined" pre-processor symbol - it's just one I made up. You can use arbitrary pre-processor symbols - and define them in your project file when you want to use them. (So in your admob project file, you'd want to define that symbol.) See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives. This isn't specific to Unity, or Google APIs - it's just part of the normal C# language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Preprocessors](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives#conditional-compilation) are not an invention of Unity but is a c# thing.

If there are no specific defines listed in the [Platform dependent compilation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PlatformDependentCompilation.html) first make sure that your packages don't bring their own custom defines. `Photon PUN` e.g. actually does bring own defines like `PHOTON_UNITY_NETWORKING`, `PUN_2_OR_NEWER`, etc. But that's totally up to the providers of such libraries.

You can see/check this in the <kbd>Edit</kbd> -> <kbd>Project Settings</kbd> -> [<kbd>Player Settings</kbd>](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PlayerSettings.html) -> `Other Settings` -> `Scripting Define Symbols`

> **Scripting Define Symbols**
> Set custom compilation flags. For more details, see the documentation on [Platform dependent compilation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PlatformDependentCompilation.html).

Then you can just invent your own ones and add them to your code like e.g. `USE_GOOGLE`, `USE_FIREBASE`, etc

```
#if USE_GOOGLE
    // some Google API related stuff
#endif
```

and later once you actually have according package in your project add these defines to the `Scripting Define Symbols` mentioned above.

---

If you know the full qualified assembly name of one **type** contained in the optional package you are looking for you can use e.g.

```
[assembly: OptionalDependency("Namespace.SubNameSpace.TypeName", "YOUR_DEFINE_SYMBOL_HERE")]
```

which is well hidden in [`Unity.XRTools.Utils`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.xrtools.utils@1.0/api/Unity.XRTools.Utils.html)!

This will internally on compile time check if the type `Namespace.SubNameSpace.TypeName` exists and if so define `YOUR_DEFINE_SYMBOL_HERE` so you can again in your code wrap the optional stuff in

```
#if YOUR_DEFINE_SYMBOL_HERE
    ...
#else
    ...
#endif
```

---

#### Alternative

For packages **you own/implemen yourself** there is a way to do this kind of automatically I used in the past. The following script as soon as it exists in a project it automatically adds the given define to the PlayerSettings if it doesn't exists yet

```
#if !USE_GOOGLE
public static class UseGoogleDefineSetter
{
    const string DEFINE = "USE_GOOGLE";

    [InitializeOnLoadMethod]
    private void Init()
    {
        // Get current defines
        var currentDefinesString = PlayerSettings.GetScriptingDefineSymbolsForGroup(EditorUserBuildSettings.selectedBuildTargetGroup);
        // Split at ;
        var defines = currentDefinesString.Split(';').ToList();
        // check if defines already exist given define
        if (!defines.Contains(DEFINE))
        {
            // if not add it at the end with a leading ; separator
            currentDefinesString += $";{DEFINE}";

            // write the new defines back to the PlayerSettings
            // This will cause a recompilation of your scripts
            PlayerSettings.SetScriptingDefineSymbolsForGroup(EditorUserBuildSettings.selectedBuildTargetGroup, currentDefinesString);
        }
    }
}
#endif
```

---

**Update Unity 2020+**

The method was semi replaced by a better one operating on a list/array instead of an entire string which is expensive. And in the newest version also the build pipeline slightly changed.

So in newer Unity versions I would rather use something like e.g. (assuming `2020` is the oldest version you want to support/use)

```
#if !USE_GOOGLE
public static class UseGoogleDefineSetter
{
    const string DEFINE = "USE_GOOGLE";

    [InitializeOnLoadMethod]
    private void Init()
    {
        EditorUtils.AddScriptingSymbol(DEFINE);
    }
}
#endif
```

and to make it easy and general

```
public static class EditorUtils
{
#if UNITY_2021_2_OR_NEWER
    private static NamedBuildTarget GetActiveNamedBuildTarget()
    {
        var buildTargetGroup = GetActiveBuildTargetGroup();
        var namedBuildTarget = NamedBuildTarget.FromBuildTargetGroup(buildTargetGroup);

        return namedBuildTarget;
    }
#endif

    private static BuildTargetGroup GetActiveBuildTargetGroup()
    {
        var buildTarget = EditorUserBuildSettings.activeBuildTarget;
        var buildTargetGroup = BuildPipeline.GetBuildTargetGroup(buildTarget);

        return buildTargetGroup;
    }

    public static void AddScriptingSymbol(string define)
    {
#if UNITY_2021_2_OR_NEWER
        var namedBuildTarget = GetActiveNamedBuildTarget();
        PlayerSettings.GetScriptingDefineSymbols(namedBuildTarget, out var defines);
#else
        var buildTargetGroup = GetActiveBuildTargetGroup();
        PlayerSettings.GetScriptingDefineSymbolsForGroup(buildTargetGroup, out var defines);
#endif

        var defineList = defines.ToList();

        if (!defineList.Contains(define))
        {
            defineList.Add(define);
        }

#if UNITY_2021_2_OR_NEWER
        PlayerSettings.SetScriptingDefineSymbols(namedBuildTarget, defineList.ToArray());
#else
        PlayerSettings.SetScriptingDefineSymbolsForGroup(buildTargetGroup, defineList.ToArray());
#endif
    }
}
```

Both scripts go of course either in a folder called `Editor` and/or in an assembly only compiled for the Unity Editor or need to be wrapped additionally in `#if UNITY_EDITOR`

Comment: That's a really great answer! Thanks :D

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The 2nd variable 'defines' at the line `var defines = defines.Split(';').ToList();` should be 'currentDefinesString', right? And Constants.Define is not declared here. Do you mind if I post an answer with a working script?

Comment: @TrongNguyen I updated the answer thanks. Note that either way this way is nowadays deprecated .. you now go with the method returning a list/array which is way more convinient and easier to avoid any mistakes by misplaced `;`